# Uploading dynamic textures fast in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures

I receive jpeg compressed video frames over network in every 30 frames. But I have a low power mobile device and it seems to lag a lot if I upload with the following lines.

```
Texture2D tex;
tex.LoadImage(MyUDPReceiver.Instance.data_JPG);
```

Are there any more efficient ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not post the complete script where you are doing `tex.LoadImage`? That will show what else you are doing wrong. How you are receiving the image matters too so you should post that as-well.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use JPEG or PNG images as their decoding is very slow. These textures are also decoded to uncompressed and use a lot of ram.

You should use ETC1 textures, of if you need the alpha channel, DXT5. Note that DXT5 is not supported everywhere so you might also need to support a different type of texture for this (PVRTC?).

There is `tex.LoadImageRaw` for this, to use it you will need to parse the header for width/height values (just a simple struct).